# How to find JAR name by using taglib URI

Tags: jsp, jar, oracle-adf, taglib

I have URI name on my JSP and I need to find in which jar its using for example On my JSP Page I have following URI

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich" prefix="af"%>
```

and I need to find out which jar its referring I almost perform all kind of search operation.

Comment: Please be more precielsy: The .tld may contained in multiple jars. The loaded jar may differs from webapp to webapp peding on the app's class-load-order. Do you like to know all occourences of the related .tld?

Comment: i think this URI will be in only one JAR not sure whether it wil be in multiple places..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [WinRAR](http://www.win-rar.com/). It is able to search in multiple compressed files in arbitrary folders. Open WinRAR, navigate to the `/lib` folder where all your JARs are and hit F3. Choose to search in all files and provide the search keyword `http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich`.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you have to search all JAR files in your classpath. Inside each JAR, look for a `.tld` file inside the `META-INF` directory, which contains the `uri` you're looking for.

In other words: look for a `.tld` file, containing the string `http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich`, in all JARs in your classpath.

Comment: @lssaac is there any other ways because for my appllcation m using more than 20 jars..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat, try

```
<%=tldLocationsCache.getLocation("http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich")
.getJarResource().getJarFile().getName() %>
```